# Youtube channel setup - Items array missing

Tags: google-api, youtube

While setting up Youtube Channel not getting the items array, when I am calling from postman using Google API Key.

Any idea how I can get that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the request your executing in Postman...

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLoison the postman API GET request

https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=<USER_NAME>&key=<API_KEY>

Comment: Could use precise a `USER_NAME` you tried with?